# How to change the basic button to fit in the background of my dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown menu on the website I'm working on. I added a logout button and the style of it is the basic one. I wanted to make the contour of the button invisible to fit with the background color, but when I added it, it changed the inside of the button but the outline was style grey and my text disappear. I added an image to explain the result.

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url "account_logout" %}" class="form-horizontal">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" class= "navbar-logout">Logout</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.path }}">
    </div>
</form>
```

```
.navbar-logout {
    background: none;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should be using a border on the same color as your nav.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove to gray border you should do this:

```
.item {
  border: 0; // Or border: 1px solid #COLOR ( read up on the border attr )
  color: #FFF;
  background: none;
}
```

You still need to style the button a little further (margins, alignments, ect)

Answer (score 0):

To make your button transparent and add a text "Sign Out" in white color. The following code works -

```
.navbar-logout {
        background: transparent;
        outline: none;
        border: 1px solid white;
        color: white;
    }
```

If you want to get rid of the border completely, change border in css to

```
.navbar-loguout{
        border: none;
}
```

To fit the button to the entire width of the navbar, use width: 100%. 
The above works if your button is inside a parent container which is your navbar. Setting width to 100% sets the button to 100% of the width of the parent container which is your navbar.

```
.navbar-logout{
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the same color as your dropdown menu:

```
.navbar-logout {
    border: solid 1px #000 ;
}
```